# Can we register PSSessionConfiguration on remote machine?

Tags: powershell-2.0

Is it possible to register a PS session configuration for machine A from machine B.
Cmdlet "Register-PSSessionConfiguration" works locally only??

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to enable PowerShell Remoting on the PC You Want to Access Remotely**

In the PowerShell window, type the following command, and then hit Enter:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts  *
Restart-Service WinRM
Test-WsMan $env:computername
```

If you’re on a home network where you want to go ahead and trust any PC to connect remotely, you can type the following cmdlet in PowerShell (again, you’ll need to run it as Administrator).

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
```

Or

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts 10.0.0.22
```

Or

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts '10.0.0.22,10.0.0.23'
```

**Register a PSSessionConfiguration**

To connect `Computer1` let us register a session configuration on the server using a domain account.
Just type the following cmdlet and then hit Enter:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1 -ScriptBlock {
  Register-PSSessionConfiguration `
    -Name SessionName `
    -RunAsCredential 'domain\mydomainaccount' `
    -Force
}
```

Now I'll use this session configuration the next time I want to run a command on the remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Computer1' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem-Path \\Computer1\c$
} -ConfigurationName SessionName
```